# Why tailwind psudo class before:: content not showing correctly?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, pseudo-element, tailwind-in-js

I wanna show index number before every li as content of **before::** psudo element. But tailwind pseudo class before:: content not showing correctly?

(I use postcss for tailwind)

Heres this project [git repo](https://github.com/mohiulislam/my-app-1) link.

Heres my nav component,

```
import React from "react";
import navData from "../data/navData.js";
class Nav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { brand } = navData;
    let items = [];
    for (const item in navData) {
      items.push(navData[item]);
    }
    return (
      <nav className="flex justify-between h-[clamp(0px,10vw,100px)] bg-base_color/75  items-center backdrop-blur-sm sticky top-0 text text-white_like">
        <span className="ml-8">{brand}</span>
        <ul className=" w-2/5 flex justify-between mr-8">
          {items.slice(1).map((a, index) => {
            return (
              <li className={`before:content-['${index}']`} key={Math.random()}>
                {a}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
export default Nav;
```

Here is my navData from another file-folder,

```
const navData = {
  brand: "Mohiul Islam",
  item1: "about",
  item2: "experience",
  item3: "work",
  item4: "contact",
};
export default navData;
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow. What does "not working" mean? Be specific about what you expect to happen, what is actually happening, and how that isn't meeting your expectations.

Comment: I edited. Please take a look now @AndyRay .

Answer (score 1):

[Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content) suggests using `attr()`

##### Referencing an attribute value

> These content utilities even support CSS features like the attr() function, which you can use to reference a value stored in an attribute:

Like:

```
<div before="Hello World" class="before:content-[attr(before)]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Change your code to :

```
{items.slice(1).map((a, index) => {
   return (
      <li before={${index}} className="before:content-[attr(before)]" key={Math.random()}>
         {a}
      </li>
    );
}
```

Or

```
{items.slice(1).map((a, index) => {
   return (
      <li className=`before:content-[attr(${index})]` key={Math.random()}>
         {a}
      </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: Not like that .Wanna show index number before every li as content of before:: psudo element. Something like **className="before:content-['index']"**.

Comment: You  are specifically looking to do it using before: pseudo class ? I just gave you work around to work with meanwhile

Comment: It's worked, but not straight-cut prosess. Taking a extra attribute to do this is excess. Any other solution? (Syntax errore: Edit your answer before={`${index}`} )

Comment: try my edit. Please correct the syntax if there are any errors. I am trying to give the conceptual view of it

Comment: Lsat solution not working at all even after correcting syntax errore `className={`\``before:content-[attr(${index})]`\``}`

Answer (score 1):

CSS has its own [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters) for that purpose

Add `[counter-reset:els]` to an `ul` element and `before:[counter-increment:els] before:content-[counter(els)]` for every `li`

```html
<ul className="[counter-reset:els] w-2/5 flex justify-between mr-8">
   {items.slice(1).map((a, index) => {
      return (
        <li className="before:[counter-increment:els] before:content-[counter(els)]" key={Math.random()}
            {a}                 
         </li>
      );
    })}
 </ul>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/xpqT3dHEUq)

Comment: Tnx but, no alternative solution i need. I wanna use exclusively index number there.